# Are subsets of vegan diets on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are subsets of vegan diets on-topic?  For example, do we welcome questions on [fruitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruitarianism) and [Raw veganism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_veganism)?

Comment: One of the problems with those diets is the high level of nonsense that the communities propagate. We'd need to be careful to separate out the truth from the nonsense.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think this community has been handling nonsense very well so far. Maybe we can offer them a place safe from the nonsense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes - I think that creating tags for such subsets (e.g. `frutarianism` or `raw`) would be useful, too.

Comment: ... because they do not have their own site, and creating their own stack-exchange might prove impossible, seeing as this, in reality much larger community (vegans and vegetarians) already has a slow start here.

Comment: @hoijui You said that hours after we started, that's a bit early to measure the viability of a site…

Comment: ouh sorry, i meant to say that this much larger community, thriving and active as it is, still took up to now to get their own stack-exchange site, simply because the process is designed this way. The fruitarians, would probably take much longer, if they'd manage at all.

Comment: @gerrit, there was an attempt to launch a vegetarianism site before, and it failed. Also, it took a long time from definition to commitment to beta.

Comment: @Turion I didn't know that.  Did it reach β?  Do you have a link to its Area51 page?

Comment: @gerrit, I can't find it anymore, so I must suspect it was deleted. I don't think it made it to beta.