# Are recipes related questions on topic or should they be moved to cooking.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, scope

I know cooking is also a great concern, **I'm not talking about removing [cooking](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking)** tag, there can still be asked [great](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/24/for-a-recipe-that-contains-fish-what-could-be-a-vegetarian-substitute-that-some) questions related to cooking (btw, I looove cooking!!).

.. but I've just seen this question [Is there an effective way to make vegan "souffle" pancakes (an airy, fluffy batter)?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/115/is-there-an-effective-way-to-make-vegan-souffle-pancakes-an-airy-fluffy-batt)

This type of questions can be endless ( think they should be moved to https://cooking.stackexchange.com), and if the site starts getting a bunch of *'how to cook this'* related questions we will lose the essence of the site, which is asking about *vegetarianism*.

BTW: I'm not [talking](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-subsets-of-vegan-diets-on-topic) about [diets](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-sorta-vegetarian-diets-on-topic)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Being on topic somewhere else doesn't make them off-topic here.

Experts in veg*n cooking will be found here  (as well as Seasoned Advice), so there's no reason to ban these questions. Actually, questions like that are part of the reason I joined this beta.

After all, there are only so many questions that can be asked about just the concepts of veg*n diets. Keeping food-preparation questions will be healthier for the community, more informative, and attract a wider audience, and probably better answers than would be found on SA.

I haven't spent much time on SA, but chances are there will be less judgment here and more understanding of what it means to be veg*n.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying to 'ban' them, just moving them over there, where I think they fit better. Cooking experts join together in that site, event if they are not veg*s they can give way better advice

Comment: I don't see any functional difference between banning them and migrating them. And I disagree, veg*ns use less conventional ingredients that experienced omnivore cooks might not understand as well as even middling veg cools

Answer (score 6):

We probably need to decide this on a case by case basis. If there is a question on how to fry broccoli, that seems more like a straightforward cooking question, but if it deals with specifics related to vegetarianism it definitely belongs here (as well as on cooking).

An example: "my grandmother always makes Christmas kale with meaty broth and ham, how can I make a vegetarian/vegan version that non-vegs like?" 
I think your pancake question is relevant, too.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about sourcing ingredients that are up to certain standards, or about health/nutrition aspects could be on topic here if they are not on cooking.SE. In any other case, I'd say what is a good idea in vegan cooking is a good idea in all cooking if it involves the same relevant ingredients :)