# Is nutrition on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

StackExchange sites have varying approaches to health and nutrition questions.

Seasoned Advice doesn't allow [health questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); Parenting doesn't allow questions [seeking medical advice](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Nutrition [seems to be on-topic at Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (as long as it's about [what you're eating](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/what-is-our-stance-on-questions-about-nutrition)).

Nutrition is obviously a topic of interest/concern for veg*ns, going by the beta's and first day's questions. However, **should there be guidelines to ensure good-quality Q&A about nutrition, and/or help make it specific to veg*nism**? (vs. general nutritional advice)

Answer (score 5):

I'd say **yes.**

However, it would depend on overall subject.  For example, [Can you achieve sufficient daily complete proteins as a vegan if you only eat grains, fruits, vegetables and other whole foods?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/10/can-you-achieve-sufficient-daily-complete-proteins-as-a-vegan-if-you-only-eat-gr). This question is about nutrition as it applies to veg*nism. (on a side note, I like that shortening of vegan/vegetarianism)

However, look at this question: [Is boiling orange or lemon peels and drinking it as a tea healthy?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/216/is-boiling-orange-or-lemon-peels-and-drinking-it-as-a-tea-healthy). This question is about health benefits, but it serves as an example pretty well I think.  This is not about veg*nism, it's about the health benefits of a food that happens to be veg*an.

Take an imaginary question: "How much vitamin B12 does your body need to live"? I'd say this is off-topic. It's certainly applicable to vegans, but it's equally applicable to non-vegans. If you don't like this example, swap out the B12 part for calcium.  Yes, it can be harder to get both of those nutrients as a vegan, but it's not specific to veg*nism.

TL;DR: yes, as long as it's about how nutrients relate to veganism, not about nutrients in general.

[Related, regarding my stance on this. I believe nutrition questions should fall under these guidelines.](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-affect-vegetarians-and-non-vegetarians-alike)