# Add related sites on StackExchange to our FAQ for on-topic questions

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

We should follow the example that [Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) set on their on-topic page in the FAQ and provide useful recommendations for other sites in the StackExchange network that might be more appropriate for questions that are barely on topic. Currently [our on-topic page](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is very light on details. So let's identify sites that are likely to overlap with ours and amend our FAQ.

Respond to this question with suggestions for sites that are likely to overlap enough with Vegetarianism that we sometimes see misplaced questions on this site. Each answer should ideally be supported with one example of a question that would have been more at home on another site.

*Note: This post originally requested changes to the screen that appears when closing questions as Off-Topic/Migration, but moderators do not have access to change that and it can only be changed by SE admins and that's only done in [very rare cases](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5779/can-we-please-add-http-sqa-stackexchange-com-as-a-migration-target/5780#5780).*

Comment: I'm not sure if we CAN add options, but I'll look at that tomorrow.. (Moderators do have the ability to migrate, so you can always flag and say "this is good for OtherSite.SE" regardless of what's in that template.)

Comment: If we can't add options, then perhaps we could just amend [our FAQ](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to be like [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where they suggest alternate sites for off-topic questions.

Comment: sorta related general explanation of establishing migration paths: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5780

Comment: @Erica ah thanks, that pretty much answers it. I think I’ll heavily edit this question to reflect our actual capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SE cooking site, [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), should be mentioned in the FAQ. This was originally [suggested by Erica](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30/1236) with example criteria for migrating questions.

> In particular, general food safety (e.g. removing pesticides and/or bacteria from food) is applicable to anybody, not just vegetarians. Just because you may eat more fruits or vegetables than an omnivore doesn't mean they don't have similar concerns.

Candidates for migration:

- [How long can tofu be kept in the fridge after its opened?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/how-long-can-tofu-be-kept-in-the-fridge-after-its-opened)
- [Do I need a tofu press to make tofu?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/do-i-need-a-tofu-press-to-make-tofu)
- [How can I make rice mylk/milk that tastes sweet without adding sugars/sweeteners of any kind?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/how-can-i-make-rice-mylk-milk-that-tastes-sweet-without-adding-sugars-sweeteners)

Comment: None of those are candidates for migration! If such questions are off-topic, I'm leaving this site! A question being on topic elsewhere does not make it off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

The SE [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/) site should be mentioned in the FAQ. Some of our questions would definitely be [on-topic](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) over there.

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> - Environmental or nutritional factors that affect health

Candidates for migration:

- [Is boiling orange or lemon peels and drinking it as a tea healthy?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/216/is-boiling-orange-or-lemon-peels-and-drinking-it-as-a-tea-healthy)
- [In Canada, how much soy for human consumption is GMO?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/in-canada-how-much-soy-for-human-consumption-is-gmo)
- [What are advantages and disadvantages of consuming Multigrain food items?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/what-are-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-consuming-multigrain-food-items)

Comment: Anything about soy consumption should be considered on topic imho. Since there is a concept of "protein combining" in relation to vegetarianism, the third question is probably ok too

Comment: Health.SE is going through some [changes](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/refocusing-from-health-to-medical-sciences) and [Fitness.SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) might be a better fit for some diet-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) beta site should be mentioned in the FAQ for questions about sustainability that are not specific to vegetarianism.

Candidates for migration:

- [Are insects a feasible source of proteins for the new millennium?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-insects-a-feasible-source-of-proteins-for-the-new-millennium)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that question is really on topic. Too late for migration though (60 days)