# Let's update our on-topic page in the Help Centre

Tags: discussion, scope

Right now our [on-topic](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the Help Centre is quite sparse and out of date. Let's work together to create a new draft for what is on-topic, taking into account [all the decisions](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) that have been made in Meta over the years. The answer is community wiki, and I'll start with what we have already.

Our community [previously expressed desire to update the Help Centre](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/1236), but we never accomplished it. I also asked the community [which related sites should we mention](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/257/1236). I'm trying again now with a more collaborative approach. Once we've reach some kind of consensus, I'll remove the [unresolved](/questions/tagged/unresolved) tag and replace it with [needs-moderator](/questions/tagged/needs-moderator) as discussed [here](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/326/1236).

Comment: I just noticed that [Riker suggested a community wiki](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/define-on-topic-and-off-topic-reasons-in-the-help-center?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment297_48) approach three years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What topics can I ask about here?

**Veganism & Vegetarianism Stack Exchange** is for questions about vegetarian and vegan lifestyles.

You've come to the right place if you have questions about issues that are unique to vegetarians and vegans, such as:

- Vegetarian cooking
- Social challenges and pressures
- Foods that are traditionally associated with vegetarians
- Staying healthy while following a meat-free diet
- Understanding the reasons why people avoid some products

Please [look around](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

**If your question is a request for medical advice for you or others, it is off-topic and instead should be directed to a physician. Such questions will be closed here.**

If your question is not specifically on-topic for Veganism & Vegetarianism Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. For example if your question has no direct relation with *vegan and vegetarian lifestyles* and is about...

- food safety and preparation, ask on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)
- growing fruits & vegetables, ask on [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)
- athletics and body building, ask on [Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/)
- world travel, ask on [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)
- an eco-conscious lifestyle, ask on [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) (beta)
- institutional knowledge of medicine, ask on [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) (beta)
- domestic household animals, ask on [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) (beta)

If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area 51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Comment: I updated the [on-topic page in the Help Centre](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) today.