# Why are raw vegetables on-topic but not raw fruit?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-votes, questions

I noticed two similar questions, one which was closed and the other left open.

- [How to avoid worm infestation from consuming raw vegetables?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/how-to-avoid-worm-infestation-from-consuming-raw-vegetables)
- [How to remove pesticides and harmful bacteria from fruits and vegetables?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/169/how-to-remove-pesticides-and-harmful-bacteria-from-fruits-and-vegetables) [closed]

Both of these questions are from askers who are concerned about getting sick from eating raw produce. The main difference seems to be that one was asked early in the beta (closed) and the other was left later in the beta (left open).

The closure of the second question prompted this [question on meta](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-affect-vegetarians-and-non-vegetarians-alike) in which the highest voted answer was this:

> If it isn't unique to vegetarians, it's not really necessary to ask here.

If we're going to stick with that, then it seems like the [second question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/how-to-avoid-worm-infestation-from-consuming-raw-vegetables) should be closed.

Comment: Have voted to reopen the closed one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question about washing pesticides off fruit and veg [was reopened](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/posts/169/revisions).

Answer (score 4):

There is [another question in the Reopen queue](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/201/are-mango-seeds-edible) which states this discussion as a reason for reopening. I only see the precedent of reopening it but no explanations/reasons for it. I will be voting reopen based on this precedent but it would be fine to have a discussion to back this up as well.

Comment: Possible reasons for the mango pits question to be on-topic: 1) vegetarians seem like smoothies a lot, to the point where I’ve seen veganism linked with having a Vitamix. 2) vegetarians and vegans especially tend to explore more of what is edible from the plant kingdom because diet is restricted in other ways 3) seeds are an important food group for vegetarians because of the lower fat content in plants generally. 4) eco-vegetarians are often motivated by overall efficiency and reducing food waste

Comment: I would love it if we could come up with a more rigorous definition of when broadly-applicable questions are still on topic and have it posted as an answer to this meta question https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-affect-vegetarians-and-non-vegetarians-alike

Comment: @NIc I agree that there are reasons for the question to be on-topic on this site, but currently it does not seem to be. Perhaps we could determine the on-topicness by the question appealing to a certain aspect from a larger set of topics that are common for veg*ns, such as ecology, morals...? So, for example, if the question I linked to here would have the added aspect of "I would not like to throw the seeds away, producing waste, if I can use them safely." then it would be on-topic as it would appeal to the ecology aspect. Might be hard to determine the topics and keep them updated though.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. It might contribute to our eventual definition but it’s not sufficient on its own. If the question had actually been written that way it would almost work better on Sustainability.SE. I’m happy to take this to chat if we want an extended discussion.

Comment: @Nic We can do that but I forget about chat quite a lot so can't vouche for my participation too much :).

Comment: I proposed a more rigorous test for on-topicness. [Check it out](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/300/1236) and let me know what you think.